# Java: how to insert integer into HashSet in ArrayList?

Tags: arraylist, insert, user-input, hashset

How do I insert an integer into a HashSet in an ArrayList without overwriting it?

For some reason, the method is updating **all** HashSets in my ArrayList with the `userInput` value instead of the HashSet at ArrayList `index`.

Part of the method:

```
  case 15:
    System.out.println("\n=== ArrayList Test ===\n");
    ArrayListOfHashSet arrayList = new ArrayListOfHashSet();

    // System.out.println("Enter size of ArrayList of HashSet: ");
    // int size = scanner.nextInt();
    ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> arrayListOfHashSet = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>(81);
    HashSet<Integer> sets = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
      arrayListOfHashSet.add(sets);
    }

    do {
      System.out.println("1. insert value to ArrayList node");
      System.out.println("2. remove value from ArrayList node");
      System.out.println("3. empty");
      System.out.println("4. print");

      int choice = scanner.nextInt();
      switch (choice) {
      case 1:
        arrayList.insert(scanner, arrayListOfHashSet);
        break;

      case 2:
        arrayList.remove(scanner, arrayListOfHashSet);
        break;

      case 3:
        arrayList.empty(scanner, arrayListOfHashSet);
        break;

      case 4:
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayListOfHashSet.toArray()));
        break;
      }

      System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue? (y or n) \n");
      c = scanner.next().charAt(0);
    } while ((c == 'Y' || c == 'y') && (c != 'N' || c != 'n'));
    break;
```

My insert method:

```
  public void insert(Scanner scanner, ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> arrayListOfHashSet) {
    System.out.print("Please enter an index: ");
    int index = scanner.nextInt();

    HashSet<Integer> hashSet = arrayListOfHashSet.get(index);

    System.out.print("Please enter a value: ");
    int userInput = scanner.nextInt();

    hashSet.add(userInput);
    arrayListOfHashSet.set(index, hashSet);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide the source code on how you are populating the arrayList.

Comment: @Karthik ok here you go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 HashSet<Integer> sets = new HashSet<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
  arrayListOfHashSet.add(sets);
}
```

You are **adding the same instance** of the HashSet to all the indices of the arrayList. Since this is a reference, its the same hashset that is there in all the indices.

You will have to change `arrayListOfHashSet.add(sets);` to `arrayListOfHashSet.add(new HashSet<Integer>());`